# SVG animation freezes after navigation starts

Tags: animation, svg, gif

I am in the process of converting some animated GIF animated spinners to animated SVG for better/sharper display on Hi-DPI screens.

One issue I've run into is that when a user starts navigating to another page, an animated GIF continues animating but an animated SVG freezes.  So if I want to have an animation that shows the next page loading, I can't find a way to get away from using GIFs.

Is there a way to have SVG animations continue animating during page navigation?

(I am specifically using Chrome for this, because if it doesn't work in Chrome I can't use it.)

EDIT: The SVG uses SMIL to do the animation.

UPDATE

After receiving no responses on this, I can't find a way to keep SVG animations animating during navigation, so I have adopted a different approach, which is to use CSS animations.

CSS animations continue animating even after navigation starts.  They are a little harder to deal with, as far as inserting into a page and integrating with other elements, but they do the trick.

Comment: what kind of animation? SMIL? CSS? Javascript?

Comment: Sorry for leaving that out.  SMIL.